# Assign an address to a function parameter that is a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct pointer declared :

```
soft_register_t* temp_reg = NULL;
```

I pass the pointer inside a function call to get the address of the desired data :

```
cargo_command_get_register_handle(reg_address, temp_reg);
```

Inside the function, I assign the address of the desired data (I have confirmed that this works and `reg` has the right data in it after execution)

```
uint8_t cargo_command_get_register_handle(uint16_t address, soft_register_t* reg)
{
    if(address > MAX_REGISTER_ADDRESS)
        return 1;

    if(&register_base[register_hash_table[address].base_index].reg_table[register_hash_table[address].sub_index]){
        reg = &register_base[register_hash_table[address].base_index].reg_table[register_hash_table[address].sub_index];
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

When then function exits, `temp_reg` is still `NULL` even if I have confirmed it is the right value inside the function. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: pointer to pointer perhaps?

Comment: **Return** the value: `soft_register_t *temp_reg = cargo_command_get_register_handle(reg_address);`  Since it's a pointer you can return `NULL` for errors.  Returning a value is much less bug-prone than passing the address of the variable.

Comment: Remember that in C you can only pass arguments *by value*. That means the value used in the call is *copied* into the functions local argument variable. Any changes to the local variable will be done to that variable only, the original value from the call won't be affected.

Comment: In C all parameters are passed "by value", that means that a copy of the argument is passed to the function. Whatever you assign to that parameter in your function is only visible in that function.

Comment: There must be a better duplicate that I just can'T find right now...